# c++ Serializing an object containing string and pointer to another object

Tags: c++, serialization

*This question is part of my University Lab work!*

I have two classes, `student` and `course`. A basic interface for both classes is shown below:

**student.h**

```
    class student
    {
    private:
        int id;
        string name;
        int course_count;

    public:
        student();
        student * student_delete(int);
        void student_add(int);
        static student * student_add_slot(int);
        int get_id();
        int get_course_count();
        string get_name();
        void set_course_count(int);
        void student_display();
        course * course_records;
        void operator= (const student &);
    };
```

**course.h**

```
class course
{
private:
    string id;
    short credit_hours;
    string description;

public:
    course();
    course * remove_course(course*, int);
    static course * add_course_slots(course*, int);
    int add_course(course*,int);
    string get_id();
    string get_description();
    void course_display(int);
    short get_credit_hours();
};
```

I've been asked to write the **student** object (only the member variables) to a file in binary mode. Now I understand I have to serialize the object but I've no idea how should I proceed. I know C++ provides basic serialization for basic types (correct me if I'm wrong) but I've no idea how will I serialize a string and a **course records variable** in **student** object (which is a dynamically allocated array) to a file.

Please ask if you need any extra thing. Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to serialize ONLY the member variables or the entire class?

Comment: @AlexHG Only the member variables of the class (I assumed you meant function serializing also). I'll edit it to make it clear.

Comment: You should also look into the boost serialization library.

Comment: @jwimberley Thanks! I'll take a look. As it's a Lab work, I have to adhere to the requirements and methods to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have best answers from ISO CPP standard.

I can not explain better than that.

Please walk through question numbers (4,9,10,11) for answers to your specific question.

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization

Comment: That's a great resource. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only trying to serialize the member variables the problem is rather trivial. Here is a small example that shows how to serialize such a simple sequence of variables into a continuous array of bytes (chars). I didn't test the code but the concept should be clear enough.

```
// serialize a string of unknown lenght and two integers
// into a continuous buffer of chars
void serialize_object(student &stu, char *buffer)
{
    // get a pointer to the first element in the
    // buffer array
    char *char_pointer = buffer;
    // iterate through the entire string and
    // copy the contents to the buffer
    for(char& c : stu.name)
    {
        *char_pointer = c;
        ++char_pointer;
    }
    // now that all chars have been serialized we
    // cast the char pointer to an int pointer that
    // points to the next free byte in memory after
    // the string
    int *int_pointer = (int *)char_pointer;
    *int_pointer = stu.id;
    // the compiler will automatically handle the appropriate
    // byte padding to use for the new variable (int)
    ++int_pointer;
    // increment the pointer by one size of an integer
    // so its pointing at the end of the string + integer buffer
    *int_pointer = stu.course_count;
}
```

Now the buffer variable points to the start of a continuous array of memory
that contains the string and both integer variables packed into bytes.

Comment: Thanks! However, just for knowledge, how would one proceed if he had to serialize an object as a whole.

Comment: You mean an object consisting only of variables?

Comment: Yep! Which could be then directly copied to a object.

Comment: And I saw that there is a public variable course_records which also need to be serialized. (course_records is dynamically allocated array).