# Exception thrown while reading elements from a binary file (Exception thrown: read access violation. _Pnext was 0xB414D4.)

Tags: c++, fstream, unhandled-exception

first of all i made a simple class:

```
class test
{
public:
    test(string name="",int age=0);
    void getData();
    void show();
private:
    string name;
    int age;
};

test::test(string name,int age)
{
    this->age = age;
    this->name = name;
}
void test::getData()
{
    cin >> age;
    cin >> name;
}
void test::show()
{
    cout << "AGE:" << age<<"\n";
    cout << "NAME:" << name << "\n";
}
```

in my main function called the getData() method to input values from user and then saved them in a binary file.
Now when i try to read the file, it does store the value in the new object of the class but i get an exception (Exception thrown: read access violation. _Pnext was 0xB414D4.)
my main function looks like this :

```
int main()
{
    ifstream os("new.dat", ios::binary);
    test b;
    os.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(b));
    b.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `os.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), sizeof(b));` -- This can never work since `b` is not a trivially copyable type.  Second reason why this cannot work is that `sizeof(b)` is a constant, no matter how many characters you have in `name`.  What you want to do is to *serialize* the `test` object.

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076010/c-serializing-an-object-containing-string-and-pointer-to-another-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are trying to read the `test` object as if it is a simple flat object. For many, many reasons, this is almost always a bad idea.

In your case, the std::string member is not a simple object at all! Under the hood, std:: string usually has at least 1 pointer member to where it has allocated the string.

If you simply save the s`test` object in one session, and restore the binary representation in another session, then you set these pointers to addresses that are now completely garbage.

The process of saving a data structure in a way that is later recoverable is called serialisation, and is a complex subject.

Comment: would it work fine if i had a character array instead?

Comment: It would resolve this issue if the string was a fixed-length array, but then you potentially leave your code open to buffer overrun attacks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are trying to read the `test` object as if it is a simple flat object. For many, many reasons, this is almost always a bad idea.

In your case, the std::string member is not a simple object at all! Under the hood, std:: string usually has at least 1 pointer member to where it has allocated the string.

If you simply save the `test` object in one session, and restore the binary representation in another session, then you set these pointers to addresses that are now completely garbage.